# How To Select the total sum of an entity that appears in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, union, unpivot

I Have two types of tractions tables where a user can be present in either one or both tables my Goal is to get a sum total for each user. the tables are as follows.

```
 users
------------+----------+
| user_id   | Name     |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | John     |
------------+----------+
| 2         |  Wells   |
------------+----------+

 shop1
------------+----------+--------------+
| trans_id  | user_id  | amount_spent |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1         |   1      |   20.00      |
------------+----------+--------------+
| 2         |   1      |   10.00      |
------------+----------+--------------+

 shop2
------------+----------+--------------+
| trans_id  | user_id  | amount_spent |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1         |   2      |   20.05      |
------------+----------+--------------+
```

Expected Result after Summing

```
------------+-------------+
| user      | Total Spent |
+-----------+-------------+
| John      |   30.00     |
------------+-------------+
| Wells     |   20.05     | 
------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select user_id, sum(amount_spent)
from ((select user_id, amount_spent from shop1) union all
      (select user_id, amount_spent from shop2)
     ) s
group by user_id;
```

That said, you have a poor data model.  In general, tables with the same columns are a very bad idea.  You should have a single table for all shops with an additional column for the shop.

If you want the name, you need to `join`:

```
select u.name, sum(amount_spent)
from users u join
     ((select user_id, amount_spent from shop1) union all
      (select user_id, amount_spent from shop2)
     ) s
     using (user_id)
group by user_id, u.name;
```

Comment: This works but I need to display the name of the users, not the ID

Comment: @Wells . . . You changed the question after I and other people answered it, thereby potentially invalidating those answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select user_id, sum(amount_spent) total_spent
from (
    select user_id, amount_spent from shop1
    union all
    select user_id, amount_spent from shop2
) t
group by user_id
```

Comment: This works but I need to display the name of the users, not the ID

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, sum(amount_spent)
from
(shop1
UNION ALL
ship2)
group by user_id
```